# sitecore scheduled publishing agent with workflow

Tags: workflow, publishing

I need to have a scheduled publishing agent that publishes all items that are in final state of workflow.

I have used following agent in web.config:
agent type="Sitecore.Tasks.PublishAgent" method="Run" interval="00:02:00".

But still they are not getting published. 
In database publishQueue table is showing items with action value skipped.
Do I need to add any action item under approved state(final state)of workflow?

Comment: Was it this blog post that you followed? http://sirchicken.blogspot.bg/2013/04/automated-publishing-in-sitecore.html

Comment: yes I have followed this

Comment: @Dmytro Shevchenko Also there is no action under approved state item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally was able to find the cause of issue.Value of **Publishing.checksecurity** was true in web.config. Publishing was happening with Sitecore/anonymous user and Publishing.checksecurity was preventing the publish.